# Change the color of column A, if values match in 3 other columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to change the color of the cell in column A for a row that matches 3 different values across the column. Using Google Sheets, I have tried conditional formatting but can't figure it out.

Example: if column C is today's date, and if column G is also today's date, and if column M has the text "test" in it, then the cell in row A gets pink.

Conditional formatting will work, but I can't figure out how to add multiple required pieces to look for. I tried recording macros too but I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following custom formula and apply the conditional formatting to column A

`=AND($C1=TODAY(),$G1=TODAY(),$M1="test")`

I created this test sheet to demonstrate:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZJXdINEzy4Gh-OOIpxpiEZSrVtaS-GnFqMbw0FKcxNE/edit?usp=sharing